# Using cx_Freeze with PyQt5, matplotlib, requests in Python 3.5.2

Tags: python, matplotlib, python-requests, pyqt5, cx-freeze

I have a folder for my app, which contains these files:

```
__pycache__ (folder)
Assets (folder)
Assets_rc.py
graphSetup.py
HomeScreen.py
LBRun.py
LeagueBoost_v1.py
profilepage.py
UserInfo.db

setup.py
```

I have been trying all day now to find a way to use cx_Freeze (since I'm using 3.5.2 I can't use py2exe or pyinstaller I think) to merge all of these together to create an exe file. HomeScreen is my main script, everything else connects to it in some way. My script file looks like this:

```
from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable
import matplotlib
import PyQt5
import requests

setup(
    name = "LeagueBoost",
    options = {"build_exe":{"packages":
["PyQt5","matplotlib","requests"],"include_files":
```

["Assets","Assets_rc.py","graphSetup.py","HomeScreen.py","LBRun.py","LeagueBoos
    t_v1.py","profilepage.py"]}},

```
    version = "1",
    executables = [Executable("HomeScreen.py")]
    )
```

Comment: What happens with the setup.py you have? What makes you think you can't use PyInstaller?